# Linux Mint Fresh Install: Mouse Sensitivity Too Low

Tags: linux-mint, mouse

I just installed Linux Mint 19 Cinammon and I'm having issues with my mouse sensitivity being too low. I went to the options and tried to increase it but the slider is already at the "max" position. I saw online people suggesting that I edit my xorg file, but newer versions of Linux appear to not use one.

Comment: 2 years and this is still not solved, even in the freshest Mint batch :/

Answer (score 3):

I had the exact opposite problem of this with Mint 18, but the solution should be essentially the same.

If you run `xinput --list --short`, you should get an output of peripherals connected along with their ID. We just want the mouse, so we can pipe it into a grep:

```
xinput --list --short | grep -i mouse
⎜ ↳ USB Optical Mouse id=8 [slave pointer (2)]
```

So the ID here is `8`

We can now pull a bunch of configuration for that peripheral with `--list-props`:

```
xinput --list-props 8
Device 'USB Optical Mouse':
    Device Enabled (115):   1
    Coordinate Transformation Matrix (117): 1.000000, 0.000000, 0.000000, 0.000000, 1.000000, 0.000000, 0.000000, 0.000000, 1.000000
    Device Accel Profile (227):     0
    Device Accel Constant Deceleration (228):       1.000000
    Device Accel Adaptive Deceleration (229):       1.000000
    Device Accel Velocity Scaling (230):    10.000000
```

`Velocity Scaling` is the one you'll want to change to get a better DPI with your mouse. you can see the ID of that in my output is `230` and it's value is `10.00`

You can change the setting with `--set-prop` as below:

```
xinput --set-prop <mouse ID> <Velocity Scaling ID> <value>
xinput --set-prop 8 230 20.0
```

This has doubled the speed of the mouse pointer from `10.0` to `20.0`

Experiment with different values until it's right for you. The higher it is, the more DPI you should cover.

Comment: Depending on the device, this properties may have a slightly different name. I use a Logitech MX Anywhere 2S, and the property is called `Accel Speed` (even though it does not affect the actual acceleration).